# how does browser know that an activex control is safe?

Tags: internet-explorer, browser, activex, webbrowser-control, security

How does IE browser know that an activex control is safe? 
Any policy or method in IE?
Thanks for any one who consider this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It doesn't "know" it, all it knows is that the developer of the control *claims* it is safe.  [This MSDN article](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa751977(v=vs.85).aspx) has more info about how this is done.